# Rxjs combine objects (the right way)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following object:

```
const myObject = {
  info: [
    { id: 'F', pronouns: 'hers' },
    { id: 'M',  pronouns: 'his'}
  ],
  items:[
    {
      name: 'John', age: 35,
      children: [
        {child: 'Eric',age: 10,sex: 'M'},
        {child: 'Andrea',age: 4,sex: 'F'}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Bob', age: 23,  children: [
        { child: 'Oscar', age: 1, sex: 'M'}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to combine this so I wil have a new Observable that looks like:

```
const newObject = {
  info: [
    { id: 'F', pronouns: 'hers', persons: 
        [{  
          name: 'John', age: 35,
            children: [
              {child: 'Andrea',age: 4,sex: 'F'}
          ]
        }]
    },
    { id: 'M', pronouns: 'his', persons:     
        [{
          name: 'John', age: 35,
          children: [
            {child: 'Eric',age: 10,sex: 'M'},
            {child: 'Andrea',age: 4,sex: 'F'}
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Bob', age: 23,  children: [
            { child: 'Oscar', age: 1, sex: 'M'}
          ]
        }]
    },  
  ]};
```

I tried varioous functions, but I think I miss a functional concept.

The filtering can be done by

```
const source = of(myObject).pipe(
  map(x => x.items),
  map(x => {
    return x.filter(y => {
      return y.children.find(y => y.sex === 'M');
    })
  }),
  map(x => {
    return x.map(y => {
      return {
        ...y,
        children: y.children.filter(c => c.sex === 'M')
      }
    })
  })
);
```

But then I'll missing the info part of the object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you needn't a observable

```
const newObject = {
  info: myObject.info.map(x => {
    const person = myObject.items
      .map((p:any) => ({...p,children:p.children.filter(c=>c.sex==x.id)}))
      .filter(p=>p.children.length)
    return {...x,persons:person};
  })
};
```

If you want an observable take account that only the first "map" is the rxjs operator map, the rest are map of array

```
of(myObject)
  .pipe(
    map(obj => {
      return {
        info: obj.info.map(x => {
          const person = myObject.items
            .map((p: any) => ({
              ...p,
              children: p.children.filter(c => c.sex == x.id)
            }))
            .filter(p => p.children.length);
          return { ...x, persons: person };
        })
      };
    })
  )
```

**Updated** corrected: in the observable is pipe(map(obj=... NOT pipe(map(this.newObject